# How Does Python Apply a Method from one Library to the Object of Another?

Tags: python, pandas, pandarallel

When using `pandarallel` to use all cores when running .apply methods on my dataframes, I came across a syntax which I never saw before. Rather, it's a way of using dot syntax that I don't understand.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandarallel import pandarallel

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'b'])
```

So far so good, just setting up a dataframe. Next, to get `pandarallel` ready, we do

```
pandarallel.initialize()
```

Next up is the bit where I am confused: to use pandarallel we call this method on the dataframe

```
df.parallel_apply(func)
```

My question is: if the dataframe `df` was instantiated using the `pandas` library, and `pandas` does not have a method called `parallel_apply`, how is it that Python knows to use the `pandarallel` method on the `pandas` object?

I presume it's something to do with the initialization, but I have never seen this before and I don't understand what's happening in the back end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your methods to a previously created object:

```
def my_func(self):
    return 2*self


pd.DataFrame.my_method = my_func

df.my_method()

a   b
2   8
4  10
6  12
```

You can even pass arguments:

```
def sum_x(self, x):
    return self+x

pd.DataFrame.sum_x = sum_x

df.sum_x(3)
a  b
4  7
5  8
6  9
```

The first argument will be the `self` as a usual method inside a class.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to happen in [`initialize`](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel/blob/master/pandarallel/pandarallel.py#L572):

```
DataFrame.parallel_apply = parallelize(*args)
```

It seems that Dataframes allow attributes to be added on later, and that's what's happening here. `parallelize` appears to be a factory function that creates functions based on the passed `args`. It seems to be creating functions to act as methods, and that method it creates is being assigned to `parallel_apply`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gave top answer to Bruno because he explained how the dataframe is passed a 'self' parameter to any arbitrary function. I do appreciate your explanation of the initialize function in pandarallel.py though!